# VScode unable to modify readonly file. It's not a readonly file

Tags: visual-studio-code, readonly

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvU2A.png)

Trying to modify a file that I've done dozens of times. All of a sudden it is flagging it as unable to modify as readonly. The only thing I've done is occasionally run it in google colab but I've successfully modified it since. I have absolutely no idea what happened. The source control won't even stage the most basic change due to it being now readonly?

Comment: Make sure you don't have it open in anything

Comment: I wish. Rebooted just to make sure.

Comment: Try right clicking on it, then go to properties and see if the "Read Only" box is ticked

Comment: I've also encountered issues with saving / editing notebooks I haven't completely figured out; anyway see this answer to see if it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418760/how-to-save-changes-in-read-only-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @learning2learn That worked, but it bothers me I still don't know the root cause. Copied the notebook to another name. Pushed the copied book. Nuked the original, but changed the name of the copied back to the original and pushed and everything worked. Still weird but thank you for getting me not to smash my laptop in a field.

Comment: @JReado I get you. I have only recently gotten into Jupyter on a steady basis, thanks to VSCode's very impressive support, this matter seeming to be on the learning curve. In my similar case I didn't know my root cause either, need to study more carefully when I have time.

Comment: @learning2learn if you have a eureka moment be sure to tag me and I will give you all the kudos! Thanks again.